# How to pass JVM argument to Teamcity using env variable

Tags: java, jvm, teamcity, jvm-arguments

I have read the Teamcity documentation and searched on this topic and found that you can pass any JVM arguments to Teamcity on startup by setting an environment variable: `TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS`

What my problem is - I couldn't find anywhere how to *actually* set the jvm arguments.
Sure, you set them in the `TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS` env variable, but HOW?

```
TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS=-Xmx1200m      <- that way?
```

What about if I want 2 or 3 options, are they separated with commas?

It is probably very obvious, but it's not written anywhere...

edit: I'm running it on linux using an init script that executes the runAll.sh as teamcity user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass them with space separated values. For ex

```
TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS="-Xmx1200m -Xms256m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export *VARIABLE*=value
```

or

```
setenv *VARIABLE* value
```

before executing the `runAll.sh`

As stated in the documentation, "you might need to reboot the machine after the environment change for the changes to have effect".